# Generate ECG signal from array in python

Tags: python, matlab, scala

i want to classification in four class
I have ECG data in .mat  file with 8k records but i want to work with python so i converted .mat file data into 
dataframe.

```
+------+-----+--------------------+
|    Id|label|            features|
+------+-----+--------------------+
|A05439|    0|[-116.0,-123.0,-1...|
|A06392|    0|[260.0,314.0,370....|
|A02894|    1|[109.0,139.0,170....|
|A06027|    0|[-52.0,-64.0,-71....|
|A07682|    0|[25.0,28.0,31.0,3...|
|A02337|    2|[-66.0,-75.0,-84....|
|A06380|    0|[-399.0,-470.0,-5...|
|A05483|    2|[713.0,855.0,1002...|
|A06720|    0|[481.0,571.0,662....|
|A03970|    2|[157.0,190.0,223....|
```

issue 1. In feature set  **have more than 9k  elements for each ID** this give heap memory problem when I pass directly to model
         I also tried by PCA to reduce the dimensionality but it's not working.

so now I'm thinking of using the array of each ID create ECG signal and I will classify using that image.
If you have a better way please suggest.

how to convert directly .mat file into ECG signal in python.?

Data (will expire after 48 hrs):

https://expirebox.com/download/9fc80dc3a0b9faab5c09265bddc07f06.html

I want output like this :

[image]

If my way is wrong please suggest good one

Comment: what do you mean when you say "I want to generate the ECG signal"? Isn't the data representing the ECG signal? Also please read [ask]. Share your code that you have developed so far and give us an example of what you are trying to output.

Comment: @Irreducible my be this will help you